# Drupal.ORG's Git Branch Model

Tags: version-control, community-official-site

There are many different git workflow branching models proposed. While I try to determine the best one for my project, I want to know what the Drupal.org community uses for Drupal Core development.

I'm curious, with respect to master, dev, release, feature, version tags, etc.

I know there are several questions here about Drupal Git workflow in general, but I'm specifically wondering what Drupal.org does for branching. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like there are different proposals to change their model, so maybe looking at their model won't help make decisions. https://www.drupal.org/node/2488266

Comment: Drupal Core development is rather peculiar process. Its Git workflow is not quite suitable for ordinary custom projects.